# how to insert a path front of path environment variable

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

here is my $PATH variable.

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

when i want to add **./**  to the PATH by placing `export PATH=$PATH:./`
i got like this

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:./
```

but i want to add the **./** in front like this

```
./:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you give is the order you get: `export PATH=.:$PATH` (the trailing `/` is optional).

But be aware that it's [not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65707/65304) practice.